# Is it possible to save PostGIS connection string in OGR add-in to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ogr, add-in

In QGIS I've saved a couple of PostGIS connections for adding data. This works fine. I've been unable to save the connections in the OGR layer converter add-in though. Has anyone found a way to do this so I don't have to type it every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother about the "OGR layer converter", it was obsolete so it was removed from QGIS (starting from 1.7).

The "Add Postgis Layer" tool will allow you to export/import Postgis connections.

Comment: I stand corrected!

Comment: I'm surprised the "OGR layer converter" would be removed as it's the only way I know of (besides command line) to export PostGIS layers to other formats.  From your comment it sounds like the "Add Postgis Layer" tool will now export so I assume that will take care of it.  I'm using 1.6 but I'll upgrade soon.

Comment: Hi, I believe that is since QGIS 1.4 or 1.5 that when you right click on a vector layer in the TOC you have a menu item called "save as..." or "save selection as..." (if you have features selected). The dialog window that will show will allow you to save your vector (so Postgis included) in another format and with another CRS.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're right. It is only an interface on to the [OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs) tool ogr2ogr, but some persistence of data would be useful. You should file a feature request on the QGIS [bug database](https://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/).

Comment: Ok, I'll file that request. Thanks for confirming that I hadn't missed something.